# Limit ACTION_MOVE area ouside circle

Tags: java, android

I have custom View for color picking and I want to restrict selector be inside circle cardview in the center.
[image]
Selector is moving by ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP.Coordinates change via this function:

```
private void updateSelector(float eventX, float eventY) {
    float x = eventX - centerX;
    float y = eventY - centerY;
    double r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    if (r > radius) {
        x *= radius / r;
        y *= radius / r;
    }
    currentPoint.x = x + centerX;
    currentPoint.y = y + centerY;
    selector.setCurrentPoint(currentPoint);
}
```

I've also written this helper function to check if selector inside cardview and it's correctly works, but I've no idea how to restrict selector go in.

```
private boolean isInBounds(float x, float y) {
    return Math.sqrt(x - centerX) + Math.sqrt(y - centerY) <= Math.sqrt(cardradius);
}
```